# passing index through react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying Reactjs and I'm building a tasks project (CRUD) but I'm stuck at the point of editing, the editing part is in another component and I'm not able to send the index of the task that will be edit, I read the documentation but I'm not capable to make it, please if someone can see my code and tell what I'm doing wrong.

the app (main)code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';

    // data
    import { todos2 } from './todos.json';

    // subcomponents
    import TodoForm from './components/TodoForm';
    import TodoFormEdit from './components/TodoFormEdit';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          todos2, mode:'view'
        }

        this.handleAddTodo = this.handleAddTodo.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit2 = this.handleEdit2.bind(this);
      }

      removeTodo(index) {
        this.setState({
          todos2: this.state.todos2.filter((e, i) => {
            return i !== index
          })
        }); 
      }

      handleAddTodo(todo) {
        this.setState({
          todos2: [...this.state.todos2, todo]
        })
      }


      handleEdit2(i) {
        this.setState({mode: 'edit'});
        //const mode = mode === 'edit';


        alert(i);

         /* alert(this.state.todos2[i].title);
          alert(this.state.todos2[i].priority);
          alert(this.state.todos2[i].description);
          alert(this.state.todos2[i].language);*/


      }

      render() {

        const todosAll = this.state.todos2.map((todo, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-md-4" key={i}>
              <div className="card mt-4">
                <div className="card-title text-center">
                  <h3>{todo.title} - { i } </h3>
                  <span className="badge badge-pill badge-danger ml-2">
                    {todo.priority}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <div>
                    {todo.description}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {todo.language}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-footer">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                    onClick={this.removeTodo.bind(this, i)}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-warning ml-2"
                    onClick={this.handleEdit2.bind(this, i)}>
                    Edit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        });

return (
      <div className="App">

        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            Tasks
            <span className="badge badge-pill badge-light ml-2">
              {this.state.todos2.length} 
            </span>
          </a>
        </nav>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="row mt-4">

            <div className="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                {/* <TodoForm onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo} ></TodoForm> */ }
                {this.state.mode === 'view' ? (
                   <TodoForm onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo} />
                ) : (
                  <TodoFormEdit index={this.state.i}/>
                )}
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-8">
              <div className="row">
                {todosAll}
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    )

  }
}

export default App;
```

and the Edit component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

// data
import { todos2 } from '../todos.json';

class TodoFormEdit extends Component {

  constructor (i) {
    super(i);
    this.state = {
      todos2
    };



  }

  render() {



      return (

        <div>
          {this.state.todos2[0].title}
        </div>

      )



  }

}

export default TodoFormEdit;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused-you pass other properties to components; why are you trying to do it differently with just this one?

Comment: Sorry I'm more confused than you, I passed the properties that aren't selected,  but the index of the object that is selected by the button I can't find the way to call it and render in my editing component. Do you have any solution of my problem or any advice? Thank you

Comment: You're passing `this.state.i` but where do you *set* `this.state.i`?

Comment: Mr Dave Newton thank you very much I did it!!! I set the index inside the state and then I passed through the component and then I called in my component this.props.index and it works

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. I'll add an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `this.state.i`:

```
<TodoFormEdit index={this.state.i}/>
```

It's not clear where you set it–I see `mode` and `todos2` state properties, I don't see `i` anywhere.